# Rest-Assured: Grabbing a JSON response inside an Array

Tags: java, arrays, json, rest, rest-assured

Lets say I have a JSON response that returns an array:

```
[
   {
      "username": "dude",
      "id": 123456,
   },
   {
      "username": "hello",
      "id": 654321,
   }
]
```

How would I grab an element in the array using using Rest-Assured? For example I would just want to grab the first element of the array and print it.

Comment: [Rest-Assured](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured) is just an library support for validating the response. You wan to work with the Json from that response you can using any libs like: [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson), [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs)

Answer (score 1):

Use following code

```
given()
    .when()
    .get()
    .then().extract().path() // or .extract().jsonpath()
```